# What does it mean? Hard to understand

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Forgive me the poor skill of understanding. I just read below from the MDS3.0. But I have trouble of get the point of below. Please help to review it . Thanks.

> Recognizing the connection among these symptoms and treating the
>   underlying cause(s) to the extent possible, can help address
>   complications and improve the resident’s outcome. Conversely, failing
>   to recognize the links and instead trying to address the triggers or
>   MDS findings in isolation **may have little** if any benefit for the
>   resident with hypothyroidism or other complex or mixed causes of
>   impaired behavior, cognition, and mood.

For the first part:

> Recognizing the connection among these symptoms and treating the
>   underlying cause(s) to the extent possible, can help address
>   complications and improve the resident’s outcome.

In my understanding . It want to said: It(recognizing....) can help address the ...., But `connection` means between the symptoms and treating... , or just among these symptoms? Thanks.

But for the second part:

> Conversely, failing to recognize the links and instead trying to
>   address the triggers or MDS findings in isolation may have little if
>   any benefit for the resident with hypothyroidism or other complex or
>   mixed causes of impaired behavior, cognition, and mood.

In my understanding . The links means `the connection among`.

It seems to say `trying to address the triggers or MDS findings in isolation` is not helpful. Because it says `...may have little if..`.

Is it correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, "connection" refers to the symptoms only.  The two verbs form the boundary between the phrases.

> (recognizing...) and (treating...) can help ...

For your second question, "little if any ..." is a common expression:  "little if any benefit" = "either no benefit or a small benefit".

So the two sentences go together well.  To paraphrase in non-medical language:

> If you recognize the connections among the symptoms and treat the underlying causes, you can improve the outcomes.  But if you just treat the triggers individually, you'll create either no benefits or a small benefit.